# What is the purpose of abstract class which doesn't have any abstract methods in it?

Tags: java, abstract-class

Java allows you to designate a class as being abstract even if it has no abstract methods in it. What is the purpose of this kind of abstract class?

Answer (score 7):

An abstract class can be used to **force derivation** and to **disallow instance creation**, even when it doesn't have any abstract methods. It might be an abstract representation of some concept that has *default* implementations for its methods.

Answer (score 1):

As Jordão noted, abstract classes can be used to prevent instance creation for abstract concepts; imagine a Window class that creates a system-level window in its constructor, but only allows for instances of ModalWindow, ModelessWindow, or DialogWindow.

Abstract classes can require constructor variables and expose protected methods and fields for subclasses. The methods may even refer to private instance variables on the abstract class.

While it is a [debated](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/65179/where-does-this-concept-of-favor-composition-over-inheritance-come-from) recommendation to "favor composition over inheritance", my view is to ensure that an abstract class devoid of abstract methods is not simply a convenient container for methods convenient to subclasses, but instead that each subclass could stand in for its superclass.

Comment: +1 for the Liskov bit... inheritance is not the right tool for code reuse.